# Separate several special rows based on row names by R

Tags: r, subset

I have a table that I want to separate some rows by row name.

```
            phi      psi
A-MET-0     NA     158.0945
A-VAL-1   -144.914  137.4733
A-LEU-2   -95.021   149.7834
A-SER-3   -82.6826  166.6769
B-GLU-4   -62.5314  -36.2634
H-GLY-5   -59.6463  -42.0355
A-GLU-6   -68.6914  -40.2354
AB-TRP-7  -63.5297  -36.769
A-GLN-8  -64.8056   -38.5128
```

I will separate a specific row according to the following command

```
tor$tbl["A-LEU-2",]
```

But when I try to separate a few rows, it gets an error.
I use the following command to separate several rows.

```
tor$tbl["A-LEU-2":"AB-TRP-7", ]
```

How can I separate several rows from the table based on the row name?

Thanks for guiding me.

Comment: Are you trying to extract those two specific rows or everything in between those two rows?

Comment: I want to separate everything in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to do that -

```
subset_by_rowname_range <- function(data, start_name, end_name) {
  rn <- rownames(data)
  data[match(start_name, rn) : match(end_name, rn), ]
}
subset_by_rowname_range(df, "A-LEU-2", "AB-TRP-7")

#              phi      psi
#A-LEU-2  -95.0210 149.7834
#A-SER-3  -82.6826 166.6769
#B-GLU-4  -62.5314 -36.2634
#H-GLY-5  -59.6463 -42.0355
#A-GLU-6  -68.6914 -40.2354
#AB-TRP-7 -63.5297 -36.7690

subset_by_rowname_range(df, "H-GLY-5", "A-GLN-8")

#              phi      psi
#H-GLY-5  -59.6463 -42.0355
#A-GLU-6  -68.6914 -40.2354
#AB-TRP-7 -63.5297 -36.7690
#A-GLN-8  -64.8056 -38.5128
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(phi = c(NA, -144.914, -95.021, -82.6826, -62.5314, 
-59.6463, -68.6914, -63.5297, -64.8056), psi = c(158.0945, 137.4733, 
149.7834, 166.6769, -36.2634, -42.0355, -40.2354, -36.769, -38.5128
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("A-MET-0", "A-VAL-1", 
"A-LEU-2", "A-SER-3", "B-GLU-4", "H-GLY-5", "A-GLU-6", "AB-TRP-7", 
"A-GLN-8"))
```

Comment: If a table has thousands of rows, can this written code be used?

Comment: @user18043726 Yes, definitely. This code works irrespective of the numbers of rows in the data. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is by inserting row numbering, which can be used as indices for `slice`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  slice(1:8)
```

Alternatively, this would work too: here, `which` grabs the `row.names`' indices, by which `slice` can filter:

```
df %>%
  slice(which(grepl("A-LEU-2", row.names(df))):which(grepl("AB-TRP-7", row.names(df))))
```